# Is this a good organic soil/fertilizer setup for container carrots?

Tags: fertilizer, soil-amendment, organic, container-gardening, carrots

I am growing 36 carrots in a 18" square container that is 14" deep. I know I have enough room for them but am more worried about whether there will be enough nutrition in the soil to carry them through until harvest.

Is there a certain soil blend or configuration (amendments) that would allow me to set it and forget it?

Some sources say to do a light liquid fertilization every 2 weeks or so about halfway through the grow cycle (35-40 days) of [FoxFarm Big Bloom](http://foxfarmfertilizer.com/index.php/item/big-bloom-liquid-plant-food.html). Is there a more apt liquid fertilizer for carrots?

Update:

I've since moved to a ~20 carrot per container setup and thus far a single grow does not need any added fertilizer but if I keep growing carrots in the same containers, after how many harvests would I need to start fertilizing. Do I need to let the soil settle on it's own at some point?

Comment: What variety are you looking at growing? Carrots have a larhe root system, so planted that close *in a 14" container* is probably not going to work unless you are using a miniature variety,

Comment: They grow up to 7" according to the seed packet. The only information is Napoli, candy carrots if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after how many harvests would I need to start fertilizing?

With the same idea as crop rotation, you probably shouldn't be growing carrots in the same soil year after year. I'd say after a couple years, bringing in fresh mix is a much better option.

> I know I have enough room for them but am more worried about whether there will be enough nutrition in the soil to carry them through until harvest.

This really depends on the mix. Some pre-fertilized mixes are advertised to feed for up to 9 months, but generally, regularly using a liquid feed as a root drench is better.

> Is there a certain soil blend or configuration (amendments) that would allow me to set it and forget it?

Basically, no. Not in so confined a container as you are using.

> Some sources say to do a light liquid fertilization every 2 weeks or so about halfway through the grow cycle (35-40 days) of FoxFarm Big Bloom. Is there a more apt liquid fertilizer for carrots?

Basically, you want a lot of phosphorus (P), also plenty of potassium (K), and less nitrogen (N). The feed you linked to looks fine. There isn't a 'best' fertilizer for a certain species, as it also greatly depends on the culture the plant is growing in.